# How to get package name/version at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm loading package at runtime via `LoadPackage()`. Let's say after load I want to check the version of the package to ensure it's the newest. How can I do that?

Comment: u may consider unit versioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251165

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A package is just a special type of dll,  So you can use the [`GetFileVersion`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.GetFileVersion) function defined in the SysUtils unit, this function returns the most significant 32 bits of the version number. so does not include the release and/or build numbers.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

 Var
   FileVersion : Cardinal;
begin
  try
    FileVersion:=GetFileVersion('C:\Bar\Foo.bpl');
    Writeln(Format('%d.%d',[FileVersion shr 16, FileVersion and $FFFF]));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

If you want retrieve the full version number (with release and build numbers included) you can use the [`GetFileVersionInfoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`VerQueryValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetFileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi functions.

```
function GetFileVersionStr(const AFileName: string): string;
var
  FileName: string;
  LinfoSize: DWORD;
  lpdwHandle: DWORD;
  lpData: Pointer;
  lplpBuffer: PVSFixedFileInfo;
  puLen: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  FileName := AFileName;
  UniqueString(FileName);
  LinfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(FileName), lpdwHandle);
  if LinfoSize <> 0 then
  begin
    GetMem(lpData, LinfoSize);
    try
      if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(FileName), lpdwHandle, LinfoSize, lpData) then
        if VerQueryValue(lpData, '\', Pointer(lplpBuffer), puLen) then
          Result := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [
            HiWord(lplpBuffer.dwFileVersionMS),
            LoWord(lplpBuffer.dwFileVersionMS),
            HiWord(lplpBuffer.dwFileVersionLS),
            LoWord(lplpBuffer.dwFileVersionLS)]);
    finally
      FreeMem(lpData);
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how to translate FileVersion to more readable form :-)

Comment: Since the file is already loaded in memory, it is actually more efficient and more accurate to access its `RT_RESOURCE` resource directly, such as with `TResourceStream`, instead of using `GetFileVersionInfo()`, at least as far as the version number is concerned since it is static data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you point me to documentation. I cannot find it.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't want you to access the `RT_VERSION` resource directly, mainly because `GetFileVersionInfo()` does some dynamic data hookups that `VerQueryValue()` looks for. So Microsoft does not really document how to access the resource directly. But if the .exe file is inaccessible or modified, `GetFileVersionInfo()` can return bad data, so it may be desirable to access the resource directly since it is already in memory...

Comment: ... it is safe to [access the resource data directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717844/how-to-determine-delphi-application-version), as long as you account for one caveat - you have to dynamically allocate a memory block and copy the resource data into it before passing it to `VerQueryValue()`, otherwise it will crash with a memory access error.